# Long running query issues

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm trying to fix some issues with a script I didn't make where the site seems to be filling up the mysql `/tmp` dir very fast.

I checked the `slow query log` and it has a lot of queries like this..

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `total`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
                *
        FROM
            `Advertising_Business_and_Retail`
        WHERE
            MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company')
    UNION
        SELECT
                *
        FROM
            `Chemical` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company')
    UNION
        SELECT
                *
        FROM `Clothing` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company')
    )
AS t;
```

Except it has I believe `45` unions in total (1 for each category table), these tables aren't huge, but the `Advertising_Business_and_Retail` table has about `450k` listings by itself.

I ran this query manually and it took about 2 and a half minutes.

I'm guessing this is why the /tmp dir is filling up so fast?

Any tips on what I can do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that there are no duplicates among the rows that you are selecting, try replacing `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Moreover, you could also replace `UINON ALL` with simple addition:

```
select (
  (select count(1) from `Advertising_Business_and_Retail` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company'))
+ (select count(1) from `Chemical` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company'))
+ (select count(1) from `Clothing` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company'))
) as total
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this any faster?

```
SELECT
    SUM(`count`) AS `total`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
               COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM
            `Advertising_Business_and_Retail`
        WHERE
            MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company')
    UNION
        SELECT
               COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM
            `Chemical` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company')
    UNION
        SELECT
                COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `Clothing` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('outdoor apparel company')
    )
AS t;
```